# MySQL - Improve Performance for Multi Country

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, lamp, database-administration

I have a table `company`, which has a column called `country_id` is a reference of `country` table Primary Key ID.

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
    `Id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `Symbol` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `Industry` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `Type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    'country_id' INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    CONSTRAINT `company_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES  `country` (`Id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In this table has multiple company for multiple country. Like the below table.

[image]

My `company` table has huge data. I want to **improve the select query on `company` table performance based on country**. Select query will be like

```
 select * from company where country_id = 2
```

What will be the best design approach? Do I need to add indexing on `country_id` column or do I need to do the partitioning based on the `country_id` column? Please suggest.

Comment: If this table is read-only (except for once-in-a-while admin purpose) you can consider using MyISAM for this table; read performances are improved on our setup for this kind of table

Comment: @Preuk, this is not a read-only table. Continuously data are inserting in this table. But my preference is to improve the select query.

Comment: If you have only two tables which only of them is huge (Over millions of rerecords) and small table (Max 200 records) why you are not Denormaliz your Table as long as both country.id and country.name are UNIQUE

Answer (score 0):

if you have big count of countries (more then 100), you should use index.

If few number countries in your DB would be better to use partitioning.
But this option has one big disadvantage. If you will add new country, you should add new partition linked to new one.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB will automatically generate index on your foreign key `country_id`, so you do not need to indexing on it.
About partition, InnoDB does not support foreign key and partition together and if you use partition you can just create an index on `country_id` (not foreign key) and join both tables if you needed.
If you have more than one million records on `company` and your query is not fast enough, you can use partition, like below:

```
    CREATE TABLE `company` (
        `Id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
        `Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        `Symbol` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        `Industry` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        `Type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        `country_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
        INDEX (`country_id`)
    )

PARTITION BY RANGE (`country_id`) (
    PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (20),
    PARTITION P2 VALUES LESS THAN (50),
    PARTITION P3 VALUES LESS THAN (100),
    PARTITION P4 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE)

    COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB;
```